# Kubernetes : Scale up/down HA cluster from single control-plane

Tags: kubernetes, scaling, high-availability

**Scenerio** Scaling up/down a Kubernetes H/A cluster from a single control-plane

**Question:** Is it possible to perform kubectl command from one control-plane and affect the other (joined) control-plane?

**Goal:** To run one kubectl command (ie. kubectl scale deploy xyz --replica 3) from one control-plane and affect the entire H/A cluster

**Example:**

```
[cluster-a]$ kubectl scale deploy xyz --replica 10

Cluster A 
- deploy-xyz-pod-1
- deploy-xyz-pod-2
- deploy-xyz-pod-3
- deploy-xyz-pod-4
- deploy-xyz-pod-5
Cluster B
- deploy-xyz-pod-1
- deploy-xyz-pod-2
- deploy-xyz-pod-3
- deploy-xyz-pod-4
- deploy-xyz-pod-5
```

--

```
[cluster-a]$ kubectl scale deploy xyz --replica 7

Cluster A 
- deploy-xyz-pod-1
- deploy-xyz-pod-2
- deploy-xyz-pod-3
Cluster B
- deploy-xyz-pod-1
- deploy-xyz-pod-2
- deploy-xyz-pod-3
- deploy-xyz-pod-4
```

--

```
[cluster-a]$ kubectl scale deploy xyz --replica 1

Cluster A 
- deploy-xyz-pod-1
Cluster B
```

Comment: You can't use single kubectl command to manage multiple clusters, but it should be possible to build a wrapper of kubectl plugin for that
You can also build one big cluster spanning multiple regions with single conrol-plane

Comment: You may be interested in [Kubernetes Cluster Federation](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubefed#kubernetes-cluster-federation).
What do you think ?

Answer (score -2):

Why not use something like https://rancher.com/ ? It should allow you to manage multiple clusters and its opensource